# classification modell complexity and distance metrics

Tags: metric-spaces, machine-learning

the titel says basically all: Are there differences in modell complexity (Bias-Variance) if someone uses (f.e.) kNN with different metrics?
Is there a mathematically background for this? In the web i haven't found anything in this direction.
Is the complexity just the same? I'm asking me that because there are really many metrics one could use
and I'm interested in a (programmable) logic.

kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Yes the choice of distance metric can have an impact on the performance of a KNN model. Different metrics measure closeness in different ways. Consider the L1 and L2 norms. The L1-norm can be said to be less sensitive to outliers and more sensitive to small scale behavior then the l2-norm, focusing on small scale behavior because it does not flatten out around zero like a parabola. It will also be less sensitive to large distances because the slope does not increase with distance from the origin.

This paper might be of interest to you;

[Effects of Distance Measure Choice on KNN Classifier Performance - A Review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.04321) by Prasath et al.

Comment: I know this pdf, my question was more about modelling the complexity of a metric in touch of kNN (f.e.). But i thought as much that there is no general answer/math. theory for it because it's to specific. Anyway it isn't very important for me, i just thought that there is any expert here who knows any theorem or kind of that..